# "A" at start of node title causes it to not be found w search_api_solr unless "a" added to search string

Tags: search

I'm having a weird issue with string grouping, I was wondering if anyone might have suggestions on what to look at.

I'm maintaining a site that has a nodes indexed at HostedApacheSolr. We're using search_api and search_api_solr for the index, and the results are being displayed using Views.

One of the nodes has a title e.g. "A Banana in the Tree eBook" and there are several other nodes which mention "a banana in the tree" in their body text. Searching for different strings return different results sets in an unusual way:

- "A Banana in the Tree eBook" (with quotes) - returns correct results.
- "A Banana in the Tree" (with quotes) - returns correct results.
- "Banana in the Tree" (with quotes) - returns no results.
- Banana in the Tree (without quotes) - returns correct results.

Anyone have any thoughts on why adding the single word "a" before "banana in the tree" would give correct results, but without the "a" it gives no results at all?